# Line Break in XML formatting? 

Tags: xml, android, line, break

when editing a String in XML I need to add line breaks. And I wanted to ask what is the RIGHT form when programming for android? Because `<br>` works but ECLIPSE marks the area as problematic. If I check out suggestions Eclipse tells me that I shall add a end tag `</br>` - IF I add that the line break dissapears...

So the one works but is marked as problematic, the other works not but Eclipse tells me its ok..

What form shall I use?

Comment: On a side-note: **Never** use `<br>`. Explaination: most markup-languages (for xml, html, etc) use `<item>` to open a tag, `</item>` to close a tag and `<item></item>` is an empty thus has an alternative notation `<item/>`. So `<br>` opens a tag, it's logic the IDE asksed to close with `</br>` but as the br-tag is almost always empty it's advisable to use **`<br/>`**. 


Anyhow the question was about Java, so `\n` is much better. Using html for a textview works fine but consumes relatively much memory. Only use this it when necessary, if you want a multicolored textview or something like that.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938403/how-to-preserve-line-breaks-in-xml-string-resources-in-android/31683548#31683548

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Use `\n` for a line break and `\t` if you want to insert a tab.

You can also use some XML tags for basic formatting: `<b>` for bold text, `<i>` for italics, and `<u>` for underlined text.

Other formatting options are shown in this article on the Android Developers' site:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Answer (score 17):

If you are refering to res strings, use CDATA with \n.

```
<string name="about">
    <![CDATA[
 Author: Sergio Abreu\n
 http://sites.sitesbr.net
  ]]>        
</string>
```

Comment: Thank you indeed!

Answer (score 4):

Also you can add <br> instead of \n.

And then you can add text to TexView:

```
articleTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(textForTextView));
```

Answer (score 4):

Take note: I have seen other posts that say `&#xA;` will give you a paragraph break, which oddly enough works in the Android xml `String.xml` file, but will NOT show up in a device when testing (no breaks at all show up). Therefore, the `\n` shows up on both.

Comment: can you tell us `&#xA;` is what format ? url of its table for all chars may be

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I use when I don't have access to the source string, e.g. for downloaded HTML:

```
// replace newlines with <br>
public static String replaceNewlinesWithBreaks(String source) {
    return source != null ? source.replaceAll("(?:\n|\r\n)","<br>") : "";
}
```

For XML you should probably edit that to replace with `<br/>` instead.

Example of its use in a function (additional calls removed for clarity):

```
// remove HTML tags but preserve supported HTML text styling (if there is any)
public static CharSequence getStyledTextFromHtml(String source) {
    return android.text.Html.fromHtml(replaceNewlinesWithBreaks(source));
}
```

...and a further example:

```
textView.setText(getStyledTextFromHtml(someString));
```