# How to insert break line for long text?

Tags: android

I want to set a long text with break line in string.xml

I couldn't insert break line for all

for example:
my text : It is a test 1.It is a test 2.
It is a test 3.
It is a test 4.
.
.
.
It is a test 500.
It is a test 501.
I want to change to:
    It is a test 1
It is a test 2
It is a test 3
It is a test 4
.
.
.
It is a test 500
It is a test 501

Comment: where you want shw this text??

Comment: use "\n"                                   ..........

Comment: Use \n within your strings. That's the escape sequence for a newline character.

Comment: Use \n for a line break

Comment: A simple search gives many answers.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877828/line-break-in-xml-formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert "\n" where you want your text to jump on next line.

I.e.:

```
myText = myText.replace(". ", "\n")
```

in xml layout:

```
android:text="My very long long\nlong long long long\nlong long text"
```

Comment: my text is very long!

Comment: Is there a way for add "\n" after ". "?

Comment: As I showed... by code, with a replace or manually in xml (you can let a text editor - even the internal one - do that for you)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this

```
<string name="sample_string"><![CDATA[It is a test 1 <br />It is a test 2]]></string>
```